# Can't use CSS for my HTML page using Electron an Nunjucks

Tags: html, css, electron, nunjucks

I have an electron app which uses Nunjucks for templating. I add

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in layout.html.
Then index.html then extends layout.html using Nunjucks. But when rendering index.html my CSS doesn't apply. However I also use Bootstrap CSS in layout.html and that works. I would like my CSS to apply to index.html. I checked the file path of styles.css, and it all works without Nunjucks. Could anyone help me please ?